# Socket hang in dnode

Tags: node.js, socket.io, dnode

I have developed a client/server bi-directional communication using dnode.
When a client connects to the server, I keep the connection so the server can use this connection to invoke a method on the client when it needs to.
Sometimes the connection seems to become inactive, I then need to restart the client manually. Could the connection remain active with some specific options ? (I though the reconnect every 3s would do the trick but does not seem to be the case).

The server is like

```
dnode(function (remote, conn) {

  conn.on('connect', function (){     // THIS METHOD IS NEVER CALLED !!! I DON'T KNOW WHY
    console.log("connection");
  });

  // Connection starts
  conn.on('ready', function () {
      // Keep remote in a hash for later usage
      ...
  });

  // Connection ends
  conn.on('end', function(){
     // Remove remote object from hash
     ...
  });

}).listen(5000);
```

The client:

```
// Define client functions
dnode(function (remote, conn) {
    // Ping
    this.ping = function (cb) {
        cb("pong");
    };

    // Other functions
    ...
}).connect(server, port, {'reconnect': 3000});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could do with [upnode](https://github.com/substack/upnode), which buffers commands and reconnects dropped dnode connections for you automatically.

I don't think the `connect` event is expected to be fired, because the function you set it up inside *is* dnode's 'on connection' handler.

You might also want to check out my [enode](https://github.com/timoxley/enode) library, which bundles upnode functionality and IMO, makes the dnode api more intuitive. It also maintains a list of active connections, handles Error objects better and simplifies disconnection and closing.

Comment: I will add upnode for a quick fix but will DEFINITIVELY rebuild the thing using enode ! Guy, your lib is terrific.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if you have any questions!